# pymongo: no such cmd: update

Tags: python, pymongo

I am using TxMongo 16.1.0 (this one uses pymongo under the hood), Mongodb 2.4.14 in my program.
I don't understand why I receive this pymongo.errors.OperationFailure:
(It cannot recognize `update` cmd???)

```
TxMongo: command SON([('update', u'units'), ('updates', [SON([('q', {'baseIP': u'10.12.59.119'}), ('u', {'$set': {'status': 'busy'}}), ('upsert', False), ('multi', False)])]), ('writeConcern', {})]) on namespace db_test.$cmd failed with 'no such cmd: update'
```

I used Son in python to make ordered dict, but still the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this might be a bug of update_one() in TxMongo.
Switch to update() will be fine.